# Generating all combinations from two lists with repetition

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations, permutation

Given 2 lists of data (list `A` & list `B`) I need an algorithm to generate all possible combination `C` such that in each combination:

- All items of `A` must be present, ordering doesn't matter (e.g., `abc` is same as `cba`)
- Exactly 1 item from `B` must be present after each item from `A`
- Items from `B` can be repeated

**Example 1**

```
A = {a, b, c}
B = {1, 2}
```

Answer:

```
a1b1c1
a1b1c2
a1b2c1
a1b2c2
a2b1c1
a2b1c2
a2b2c1
a2b2c2
```

**Example 2**

```
A = {a, b}
B = {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer:

```
a1b1
a1b2
a1b3
a2b1
a2b2
a2b3
a3b1
a3b2
a3b3
```

What algorithm can I follow to generate this answer? Thanks. I see the pattern, but unable to translate it to code. I'll be coding in C++, but an algorithm will work for me.

I've checked the following questions on SO about this topic. But none is like my problem.

[How to find all combinations of sets of pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909992/how-to-find-all-combinations-of-sets-of-pairs) - doesn't allow repetition on 2nd set.

[All combinations of pairs within one set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761749/all-combinations-of-pairs-within-one-set) - deals with one set.

[combinations between two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists) - doesn't allow repetition on 2nd set.

[Finding all possible value combinations between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058868/finding-all-possible-value-combinations-between-two-arrays) - doesn't allow repetition on 2nd set.

[An efficient method to generate all possible ways to pair up items in a data set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447697/an-efficient-method-to-generate-all-possible-ways-to-pair-up-items-in-a-data-set) - deals with single set, doesn't allow repetition.

I couldn't come up with a minimum example, as I don't know the algorithm.

Comment: Being a member for so long with that many questions, you really show know better. Time to re-read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [re-take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [re.read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And of course re-learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons your question might be down-voted. Finally, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: OK. Edited my question. You thought this is yet another pairing question? Probably that's not true and before posting here I searched for answer but couldn't find one. I know how to debug, but I couldn't code as I don't know the algorithm! Thank you, idownvotedbecau.se is interesting.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Sorry I'm missing - where you're seeing the application of permutation in the problem?

Comment: @Donotalo excuse my poop comment. I read "an algorithm to generate all possible combinations" and thought "permutation problem" I judged too soon. Still, this can't be so hard, not?

Comment: @JHBonarius, it wasn't a poop comment. If you look solely at the elements from `b`, those are permutations with repetition of length `a.size()`

Comment: From the suggested result, it seems you must always alternate one element from `A` and one element from `B` for each output, is this correct? Moreover, it seems you don't reorder the element from `A`, the outcome is always `aXbYcZ` in your example.

Comment: According to your bullet list of requirements these should also be solutions to Example 1: cba1, abc2, 1abc, a2bc. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @acraig5075: You're right. I've fixed the description. This is a part of another problem and I had difficulty figuring out a description of what I was looking for. All I knew is the input and output.

Comment: This is a Cartesian product of B with itself, as many times as there are elements in A, with the results then decorated by using the constant A values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution, I make a counter – a vector with size of first list which stores iterators in second list. Then, everything becomes very easy (and even does not need much code for implementation.)

My sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

typedef std::list<char> List1;
typedef std::list<int> List2;
typedef std::vector<List2::const_iterator> Counter;

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const std::pair<List1&, Counter&> &pair)
{
  Counter::const_iterator iter = pair.second.begin();
  for (const List1::value_type value : pair.first) {
    out << value << **iter++;
  }
  return out;
}

bool count(const List2 &lst2, Counter &counter)
{
  for (size_t i = counter.size(); i--;) {
    if (++counter[i] != lst2.end()) return false;
    counter[i] = lst2.begin();
  }
  return true; // wrap-over
}

int main()
{
  List1 lst1 = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
  List2 lst2 = { 1, 2 };
  // make/fill counter
  std::vector<List2::const_iterator> counter(lst1.size(), lst2.begin());
  do {
    std::cout << std::pair<List1&, Counter&>(lst1, counter) << '\n';
  } while (!count(lst2, counter));
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a1b1c1
a1b1c2
a1b2c1
a1b2c2
a2b1c1
a2b1c2
a2b2c1
a2b2c2
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/616970b9624fe79d)</kbd>

It's simply working like a [trip meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometer#Trip_meters) where the first list provides number and labels of columns, and second list provides the values of columns:

[image: Trip Meter in Wikipedia]

Answer (score 1):

These are permutations with repetition of the elements from `B` in disguise. If you are looking only at the elements from `B` (example from the OP) we have:

```
111
112
121
122
211
212
221
222
```

Which are precisely the permutations of `B` with repetition. The elements from `A` are simply filled in to obtain the desired result.

```
template <typename typeVec1, typename typeVec2>
void customPerms(typeVec1 a, typeVec2 b) {

    int r = a.size(), n = b.size();
    int r1 = r - 1, n1 = n - 1;
    std::vector<int> z(r, 0);
    int numRows = (int) std::pow(n, r);

    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; ++j)
            std::cout << a[j] << b[z[j]];
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int k = r1; k >= 0; --k) {
            if (z[k] != n1) {
                ++z[k];
                break;
            } else {
                z[k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it we have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Example 1 : " << std::endl;
    std::vector<std::string> a1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
    std::vector<int> b1 = {1, 2};
    customPerms(a1, b1);

    std::cout << "\nExample 2 : " << std::endl;
    std::vector<char> a2 = {'a', 'b'};
    std::vector<int> b2 = {1, 2, 3};
    customPerms(a2, b2);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
Example 1 : 
a1b1c1
a1b1c2
a1b2c1
a1b2c2
a2b1c1
a2b1c2
a2b2c1
a2b2c2

Example 2 : 
a1b1
a1b2
a1b3
a2b1
a2b2
a2b3
a3b1
a3b2
a3b3
```

Here is a working example : https://ideone.com/OUv49P

Comment: this could very intrestingly be converted to work for combinations of N lists.

Comment: Another way to say "permutations with repetition" (more standardly, permutations with *replacement*) is that it is a Cartesian product of B with itself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, First off, I've seen many ways to describe he fact that elements are non-distinct: e.g. "permutation with {repetition|replacement|repeats allowed|non-distinct}". I wouldn't say _replacement_ is the standard way. Many of the articles I run into daily use _without repetition_ or _with repetition_. See for example the wikipedia articles for [combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) and [permutations without repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_without_repetitions)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, Secondly, you are right "permutations with repetition" are equivalent to the Cartesian product of B with itself. However, one could argue that the Cartesian product and permutations are fundamentally different as generating the product requires multiple objects where as generating permutations require a single object. I wrote more about this topic here [Non-redundant version of expand.grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68050873/4408538). FYI, `expand.grid` generates the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

Many possible solutions for this. Mine's building a string with a recursive call:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using charVec = std::vector<char>;
using intVec = std::vector<int>;

void printEl(const std::string& start, charVec::const_iterator it, const charVec::const_iterator& endIt, const intVec& iV)
{
    if (it == endIt)
    {
        std::cout << start << "\n";
        return;
    }
    for (const auto& iVel : iV)
    {
        printEl(start + *it + std::to_string(iVel), it + 1, endIt, iV);
    }
}

void printComb(const charVec& cV, const intVec& iV)
{
    printEl("", cV.cbegin(), cV.cend(), iV);
}

int main()
{
    charVec A1{ 'a', 'b', 'c' };
    intVec B1{ 1, 2 };

    printComb(A1, B1);

    std::cout << "next example: \n";

    charVec A2{ 'a', 'b' };
    intVec B2{ 1, 2, 3 };

    printComb(A2, B2);
}
```

[live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cfgbqCLRa1ui2ol7)

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions possible indeed, here is a my simple recursive solution, pretty similar to JHBonarious's but without the **niceness** of production code.

```
void permute_helper(vector<string>& A, vector<string>& B, int ii, string curr)
{
    if(ii == A.size())
    {
        cout << curr << endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < B.size(); ++i) permute_helper(A, B, ii + 1, curr + A[ii] + B[i]);
}

void permute(vector<string>& A, vector<string>& B)
{
    permute_helper(A,B,0,"");
}

int main() {
    vector<string> A = {"a","b","c"};
    vector<string> B = {"1","2"};
    permute(A,B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What do you mean with "production code"?

Comment: @JHBonarius the constness, the typedefs, the pretty variable names, the iterators, the aliases - not that its bad, don't get be wrong. I find people get tangled and forget about the core question, which is the algorithm. Could even be pseudo code. :)

Comment: Hmm, I partially agree. The code should in that case at least be self-explinatory. Yours is leaning on mine a bit now. IMHO We don't want to give askers the answers, we want them to understand them.

Comment: Absolutely, just answers are no good, and I tend to provide long explanations to most of my answers. I wouldn't even have posted this but since I had already written it, I added it. If you think there less value/contribution, I can remove it.

Comment: No, feel free to keep it. It can always be useful for others, and that's what SO is about.